# Eclipse Indigo SR2 - Unable to show variable value when debugging AbstractMap

Tags: java, eclipse

Running a very simple code snippet here:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        HashMap<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map1.put(1, "A");
        map1.put(2, "B");
        map2.put(1, "A");
        map2.put(2, "B");
        boolean b = map1.equals(map2);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

When I step into the equals method of `AbstractMap`, value of any variable is not shown when hovering over them:

[image]

[image]

The breakpoints works normally, but cannot watch value of any variable. My eclipse is working OK, but only has trouble debugging `AbstractMap`.

Comment: What's shown in the actual *Variables* view?